# clearing interval inside highcharts (React)

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

I'm trying to make a live chart (dynamic data) with highcharts and I needed to set interval inside the chart options and now I can't clear the interval out (this is with functional components) because it is within a const and series.addPoints only work within the chart options I cant relocate it

```js
const getData = async() => {
  const res = await getEquipmentChart(id, Date.now() - 1, Date.now(), chart);
  return res ? .charts ? .[chart];
};


chart: {
  type: 'spline',
  animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
  marginRight: 10,
  events: {
    load: function() {
      // set up the updating of the chart each second
      var series = this.series[0];
      setInterval(function() {
        getData().then((res) => {
          var x = new Date().getTime(), // current time
            y = parseFloat(res ? .[0] ? .[subchart]);
          series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
        });
      }, 1000);

      // React.useEffect(() => () => clearInterval(i));
    },
  },
},
```

Comment: What is your issue ?

Comment: @TheTisiboth when unmounting I cant clear the interval since the interval is in the options of highchart and       // React.useEffect(() => () => clearInterval(i));
this wont work within because of hook rules

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The clearest way seems to be to use a chart component reference and then initiate and clear interval in `useEffect` hook.

```
const HighchartsChart = () => {
  const chartComponentRef = useRef(null);
  const [options, setOptions] = useState({...});

  useEffect(() => {
    const chart = chartComponentRef.current.chart;
    const series = chart.series[0];

    const updateInterval = setInterval(() => {
      series.addPoint(...);
    }, 1000);

    return () => clearInterval(updateInterval);
  }, []);

  return (
    <HighchartsReact
      ref={chartComponentRef}
      highcharts={Highcharts}
      options={options}
    />
  );
};
```

---

**Live demo:** https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-fork-5pl16?file=/demo.jsx

Comment: sadly I still have the error: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data') where the error is coming from is from series.addPoint(...) when component is unmounted idk why this is having a trouble stoping the interval

Comment: Hi @Ramtin, Please add checking if chart and series exist before calling the `addPoint` method: `if(chart && chart.series) { series.addPoint(...); }`

Comment: I fixed it using try catch error handling and if it cought an error it would stop the interval thanks!

Comment: may i know where did you put the try catch handling?